# Mapbox: Cant add LocationLayer plugin in gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, mapbox

when I try to include the LocationLayer plugin in my gradle file I get an error.
The traffic plugin and building plugin work fine.

The error:

```
Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extension:1.0.0-alpha3

Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3
```

build.gradle:

```
repositories {

mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {

    //Mapbox
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Navigation
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.3.1'
    //Location layer
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.1.0'
    //Google Play Location Service
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    //Geolocation
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-ui:2.1.3'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html), could you try adding `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to your `repositories` and refresh Gradle? It should basically look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add this dependency :

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.10.0'
```